# How can I remove a strange padding in my HTML div?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm building a layout with CSS, customizing some 'div' tags. On of them (the div with the id "col3") is with a strange padding-top and I don't know why. I have already tried to use 'padding: 0;', but it's not working. I know I can fix it with the property 'position', but why is it happening with my div? The codes are these:

HTML

```
  <section id="getintouch">
        <h3>Get in Touch</h3>
        <p>Etiam at mi at quam suscipit auctor a ac urna. Nullam non euismod felis, sed rhoncus risus. Donec erat enim, convallis eu facilisis at, hendrerit sed ligula.</p>
        <div id="getintouchlayout">
            <div id="col1-2">
                <form action="#" method="POST">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>   
                    <input type="text" name="nome" id="name">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>   
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
                    <label for="message">Message</label>   
                    <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send Message">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="col3">
            <address>
                <p>
                    <span>Endereço</span>
                    1234 Somewhere Rd. Nashville, TN 00000 United States
                </p>
                <p>
                        <span>Telefone</span>
                        000-000-000
                </p>
                <p>
                        <span>Email</span>
                        email@server.com
                </p>
            </address>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
    #getintouchlayout{overflow: auto;}
#col1-2{
    width: 63.5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    float: left;
}
#col3{
    width: 31.5%;
    float: right;
}
```

Obs: I know 'float' is not so used to do that, but I am using it because I am learning about this property in a course and I need to use it in a project.

Comment: Can you please be more specific as to where the issue is appearing?

Comment: are you talking about the default margin of the `<p>` tags inside the `<address>` block? Try adding `p { margin: 0 }` to your stylesheet and remove that `bottom: 20px;` as a test and see

Comment: Nothing unexpected; `p` just has inherent `padding-top`, which `label` does not have. You'll either need to remove the `p` padding or set some on the label.

Comment: I removed the 'p' margin and it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `<p>` margin, that tag has inherent paddding that `<label>` does not have.